# How is the limited evaluated for this problem?

Tags: limits

Evalute $$\lim\frac{\sin(8x)}{-8x}$$

I understand that $$\lim\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$
The answer in the coursera calc. self-paced non-credit course is $-1/1$

I got $1/-1$

I would greatly appreciate it if I could be walked through each step and rational to arrive at the solution.

Comment: Note that $(-1)/1=1/(-1)$ so the answers do not disagree.  Most would simplify it to $-1$

Comment: Check out this [guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
It will help you to improve your post

Comment: Thanks very much for the response! I am more concerned with the process of how the answer was derived and appreciate such and explanation. I will also use the guide for future posts

Comment: Lastly Michael, could you please give me an example of how to uses the TxT in the guide to express and represent a limit in this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin 8x}{-8x} = -\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 8x}{8x} = -\lim_{u\to\text{ ??}}\frac{\sin u} u
$$
where $u=8x$.  Now notice that as $x\to0$ then $u\to 0$, so we fill in the blank:
$$
-\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\sin u} u = \cdots
$$

Comment: Thanks Michael, I am a bit confused on the ... part. I know I should divide to get rid of the 8/-8 but get messed up with the signs and division. Also why if x -> 0 than u-> 0 as well? Thanks very much!

Comment: Also hod do you change signs in limx→0sin8x−8x=−limx→0sin8x8x

Comment: Got it Michael so I shoud say how do we change the sign here :\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin 8x}{-8x} = -\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 8x}{8x}

Comment: @ChrisRigano : Firstly, notice that $\dfrac A{-B}=-\dfrac A B$.  Then notice that $\lim (-C)=-\lim C$ because multiplication by $-1$ is a continuous function. ${}\qquad{}$